# How to increase id inside while loop?

Tags: php, loops, mysqli

code:

```
while (($row= fgetcsv($file_data, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
{
    $product_id = date('mdHis');
    $data[] = array(
             'product_id' => $product_id
         );
}
```

In this code I am importing csv file which work perfectly. Now, When I insert csv file data into my database then I am also insert an id i.e. `product_id` Now, when I click on submit button then It store same value but I want to store different `product_id` for a different row. So, How can I do this? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: Please show us all the relevant code (like the existing database code) with some examples of the data. Also, your loop doesn't really use anything from the csv?

Comment: ...and this: `date('mdHis');` will return the same number for all iterations per second (there could be a lot of iterations in a second).

Comment: Sir, Actually I want my ` product_id` auto increment if in my csv file have 100 records then it `product_id` like 1,2,3,4,5 as per row but now it remain same i.e. 1,1,1,1 which I don't want. @MagnusEriksson

Comment: If you make a column in your database which is primary key and auto-incremented then there will be no need  to do it manually. You want it manually done or will Database auto-incremented column do the job?

Comment: Isn't it easier to set a column in your database as `auto-increment` (which is the recommended approach) and let the database handle that?

Comment: But Sir, How can I make `date('mdHis')+1` @MagnusEriksson

Comment: Do you know about `auto-increment` columns but don't want to use one here for some reason, or do you not understand how or why you would do so?

Comment: If you want to do it manually, define a variable before the loop `$i = 1;` and then replace the date()-function with: `time() . ($i++);`. That will give you a unique integer on each iteration. However, I would still recommend letting the database handle this.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to just use auto-increment in the database, you can additionally use a date_created column, with the time. A loop is too fast for date() (s is seconds!), but even microtime() would not really make much sense.

If you want to really do this, why ever, in php:

```
function generateTimeID($start, $format_string) {
    while (True) {
        yield date($format_string) . $start;
        $start ++;
    }
}

$time_generator = generateTimeID($last_id_from_database, 'mdHis-');

while (($row= fgetcsv($file_data, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
{
    $product_id = $time_generator->value();
    $time_generator->next();
    $data[] = array(
             'product_id' => $product_id
         );
}
```